# How do I write a JavaScript function that prints "Hello World" every 3rd time it is called?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can we use Proxy to achieve this?

Comment: It's kinda weird to edit your question in such a way that it no longer even remotely resembles the original...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need the function to somehow have *state* (or use an outer variable) - for example, you could have a counter, increment that counter every time the function is called, and if the counter modulo 3 is `0`, print the text.

```js
const fn = (() => {
  let count = 0;
  return () => {
    count++;
    if (count % 3 === 0) console.log('Hello World');
  };
})();
fn();
fn();
console.log('about to call for third time');
fn();
```

Another option is to have `count` outside of `fn`, like:

```js
let count = 0;
function fn() {
  count++;
  if (count % 3 === 0) console.log('Hello World');
}
fn();
fn();
console.log('about to call for third time');
fn();
```

but that's less self-contained, and `count` could then be modified by other things in the same scope, which you don't want, thus the IIFE.

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter = 0;

function helloWorld(){
    counter++
    if(counter % 3 == 0){
        console.log("hello world");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. It's important to understand that here on SO we encourage answerers to offer some explanation of code they post and what was done to solve the problem. As a new contributor you may not know this but code only answers like this are *very likely* to be downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
var counter=0;

function hello(){
 counter++;
 document.getElementById('div_for_counter').innerHTML='attempt - '+counter;
 if(counter==3){
  alert('Hello World');
  counter=0;
  document.getElementById('div_for_counter').innerHTML='counter => 0';
 }

}
```

```html
<div id="div_for_counter">counter => 0</div>
<input type="button" value="Hello" onclick="hello();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way without explicit state, generators can do interesting stuff:

```
var f = function* k(){ yield; yield; console.log("Hello World") }()

f.next();
f.next();
f.next(); // Prints "Hello World"
```

In most simple terms, generators are functions that can yield multiple values and pause in between each yield statement, until their `next` method is called again. You can create infinite iterators (such as for fibonacci series) or create streams etc. This is just abusing the behavior to pause it 3 times within the function body.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you need to keep track of some state. Another way to do it while keeping it encapsulated to the function is use `this`.

```js
function fn() {
  this.called = this.called + 1 || 1;
  if (this.called % 3 === 0) console.log('Hello World');
}
fn();
fn();
console.log('about to call for third time');
fn();
```